# Data Freshness: Google Data Studio needs Manual Refresh

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am having trouble getting the data freshness of my BigQuery connector in Google Data Studio to update every 15 minutes. I have of course changed the freshness to be of 15 minutes intervals and I have editor privileges.

It seems that I have to manually refresh the browser or use a Google Chrome extension that does this automatically in order for the cache to update the data. The cache does not update automatically without a refresh of the browser.

Is this the case? I was hoping the data would refresh itself every 15 minutes, without human intervention. This is especially frustrating as it exits full screen mode.

I am uploading new data to BigQuery every 10 minutes, so I do know that there is new data.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind Data Studio predictive cache, where Data Studio executes queries in the background, please refer to the official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?hl=en).

> Every component in a Data Studio report gets its data from the cache when possible.

In the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio#create_a_chart_using_a_custom_query), you can find an explanation, how Data Studio is using BigQuery. The queries from Data Studio are related to the Data Studio product and the way it is functioning, BigQuery simply executes the queries that are being sent by Data Studio. You can also find the activity that is coming from Datastudio in the [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) .